# Javascript for loop doesn't seem to be changing the value of 'i'?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for-loop

I'm trying to run this loop in which I would like the value of 'i' to change.

However, the value seems to be stuck at zero for all 4 iterations of the loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){

        client.query('SELECT curattend FROM table1 WHERE ind=("++i++")', function(err,result){
        att = result[0].curattend;
        console.log(att)
        });
}
```

Does anyone have any advice on why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: You've hard coded `result[0]` instead of using `result[i]`. Perhaps you also intend to concatenate into the string?

Comment: Even if you use `result[i]`, I would assume that `client.query` is asynchronous, which means you'll still get an undesired result. If so, find one of the hundreds of questions that deal with assigning a handler in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't include the variable `i` in your query, you just queried for the hardcoded string `("++i++")`.

This:

`client.query('SELECT curattend FROM table1 WHERE ind=("++i++")', function(err,result){`

should be:

`client.query('SELECT curattend FROM table1 WHERE ind = ?', [i], function(err,result){`

Comment: It technically doesn't matter in this example, but you should be in the habit of using placeholders (the `?`, above) when building query strings that will be passed to the database. Almost every database client library has an equivalent feature and it lets the database client library do proper escaping and sanitization of the input parameters. Sometimes, you may not be as sure what the value looks like, and using simple string concatenation can be a major security issue.

Answer (score 2):

You've put "++i++" inside a string enclosed with single qoutes ('). You must use single quotes to escape the string as well.

Use this:

```
client.query('SELECT curattend FROM table1 WHERE ind=('+i+')', function(err,result){
```